# Why is it important that every (infinite) dimensional vector space has a (hamel) basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, hamel-basis

An argument often used in favor of the axiom of choice is that it is equivalent to every  infinite dimensional vector space having a hamel basis. However the article on wikipedia says that those basis are usually not very useful when they're uncountable, and that other concepts such as "orthogonal basis" are more important in these cases.

So why does it matter whether infinite dimensional vector spaces have hamel basis?

Comment: Showing that orthonormal basis exists usually also uses some form of choice.

Comment: There are probably also more important reasons (i.e., more fundamental consequences) to accept the axiom of choice. But it's a good question anyway. I recall that a Hamel's basis of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is used to "construct" nonstandard functions $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$.

Comment: Hamel basises are good for constructing counterexamples. I.e., to construct discontinuous linear functionals. (But not much more imho)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One interesting element is that if two vector spaces over the same field have the same dimension, they are isomorphic. So identifying the cardinality of a Hamel basis is a way to identify isomorphic vector spaces.